# Search specific JSON data using angularjs tied to ng-model enteredData

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-model

I am using Angular trying to search JSON data for a specific Name entered by user.  I am passing entered data into clickButton function, using angular.forEach for iteration and pushing the key/value into results.  Example: Type Sam in a form, click search and it finds all Sam JSON data.
Fiddle [a link](http://jsfiddle.net/al321/s4cLbL19/1/)!

```
   angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', 
   ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
   $scope.stuff = {
   "People": {
    "Sam":[
   {"Name":"Sam", "Address":"Street","Phone":"111", "status":"Available"}], 

    "Tom": [
{"Name":"Tom", "Address":"Road", "Phone":"222", "status":"Busy"}
    ]};
};

$scope.results = [];

$scope.clickButton = function(enteredValue) { 

     $scope.items = $scope.stuff.People;
      $scope.text='You searched for:';

    angular.forEach($scope.items, function(value, key) {
      if (key === enteredValue) {
        $scope.results.push
    ({name: key, address: value[0].Address,     phone: value[0].Phone });
      }
    });

  };
```

Comment: So what is the problem?
Are you just trying to display data?  filtering an ng-repeat would be better for that.  Easier too.

Comment: Just added Fiddle Trying to type Sam and display all same results in table.  Clear.  Then Type in Tom to display Tom's data in table.  http://jsfiddle.net/al321/s4cLbL19/1/  The table will be empty on Page Load

Comment: First of all you've got a typo error. Check your console.

Comment: you also instantiated the controller twice.

Comment: Everything seems fine after fixing your typo http://jsfiddle.net/s4cLbL19/6/

Comment: your HTML mark up is invalid and the `people` object shouldn't have a trailing `;`

Comment: Great.  Thanks guys it works fine.  So now I will place this data in ng-table/grid or smart table.  I have played around with NG table and like its ability to sort, filter, plus pagination out of the box.  Question.. I will click on the column and place all data associated with that Json id into form(populate a form).  Should I use Ng-Table or Smart table?  Fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/al321/s4cLbL19/7/).

Answer (score 0):

You've made a lot of small errors. The easiest way to develop an angular app is to start with something that works and keep going from there. Don't write it all out sort-of-right cause then it'll be quite hard to figure out how to correct it.

The biggest problems I ran into were:

- Your html markup should be valid
- Declare app and controller exactly once
- Include angular(!)
- Tell jsfiddle where to put the javascript
- Your JSON data structure is more complicated than it needs to be

Also, if you want to filter an array, you can use `filter`.

```
<tr ng-repeat="result in people|filter:enteredValue">
```

I've updated your fiddle to a working state: http://jsfiddle.net/utr0z73c/1/

Comment: Thank you.  Will keep this in mind for the next round.  http://jsfiddle.net/al321/s4cLbL19/7/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter.

```
ng-repeat="person in people | filter: q"
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/rnzeqqd5/

You can also choose which properties you want to filter (let's say search only by lastname):

```
ng-repeat="person in people | filter:{ lastname: q }"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rnzeqqd5/1/